M is composed of line segments connecting ellipse to $(0,0,0)$ Calculate integral $\int_M \sqrt{x + 3z}\ d \lambda_2$ over those. Almost done.
I found such an exercise among my set of exercises preparing for exams and I have no idea how to solve that.

Every point of ellipse $\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 = 1, x + z = 1 \}$ is connected to the point $(0,0,0)$ with line segments. Set $M$ is created by all such line segments excluding the points at their ends. Prove that $M$ is a manifold and calculate the integral:
$$\int_M \sqrt{x + 3z}\  d \lambda_2$$

I made such a picture. Set $M$ is denoted by green colour.

Manifold proof
In the next paragraph, I calculated the determinant of jacobian matrix and it is never equal to 0. Therefore we know that it is indeed a manifold.
Integral
On the eclipse, we can use cylindrical parametrization:

$x = r \cos \alpha$
$y = r \sin \alpha$

Form the first equation: $x^2 + y^2 =1 \implies r^2 \cos^2 \alpha + r^2 \sin^2 \alpha = 1 \implies r^2 = 1 \implies r = 1$.
From that and second equation we have: $x + z = 1 \implies z = 1 - \cos \alpha$.
Therefore, when we are on the elipse, we have:

$x = \cos \alpha$
$y = \sin \alpha$
$z = 1 - \cos \alpha$

To facilitate movement on line segments from $(0,0,0)$ to the eclipse we put additional parameter t that belongs to $(0, 1)$. Therefore, we can parametrize set M by:

$x = t \cos \alpha$
$y = t \sin \alpha$
$z = t - t \cos \alpha$

Now, it's necessary to calculate the determinant of Jacobian matrix for such parametrization:
\begin{pmatrix}
cos \alpha & -t sin \alpha \\
sin \alpha & t cos \alpha \\
1 - cos \alpha & t sin \alpha
\end{pmatrix}
It's not square, so we need to multiply by a transposition. We get:
$$\begin{pmatrix} cos \alpha & -t sin \alpha \\ sin \alpha & t cos \alpha \\ 1 - cos \alpha & t sin \alpha \end{pmatrix}^T \cdot \begin{pmatrix} cos \alpha & -t sin \alpha \\ sin \alpha & t cos \alpha \\ 1 - cos \alpha & t sin \alpha \end{pmatrix} = $$
$$\begin{pmatrix} cos \alpha & sin \alpha & 1 - cos \alpha \\ -t sin \alpha & t cos \alpha & t sin \alpha \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} cos \alpha & -t sin \alpha \\ sin \alpha & t cos \alpha \\ 1 - cos \alpha & t sin \alpha \end{pmatrix} = $$
$$\begin{pmatrix} cos^2 \alpha + sin^2 \alpha + (1 - cos \alpha)^2 & cos \alpha (-t sin \alpha) + sin \alpha (t cos \alpha) + (1 - cos \alpha)(t sin \alpha) \\ (-t sin \alpha) cos \alpha + (t cos \alpha) sin \alpha + (t sin \alpha)(1 - cos \alpha) & (-t sin \alpha)^2 + (t cos \alpha)^2 + (t sin \alpha)^2 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$ = \begin{pmatrix} 2 - 2 cos \alpha + cos^2 \alpha &
t sin \alpha (1- cos \alpha) \\ t sin \alpha (1 - cos \alpha) & t^2 sin^2 \alpha + t^2 \end{pmatrix}$$
Determinant of that matrix is equal to:
$$(2 - 2 cos \alpha + cos^2 \alpha)(t^2 sin^2 \alpha + t^2) - ((t sin \alpha (1- cos \alpha))(t sin \alpha (1 - cos \alpha))) =$$
$$= 2t^2 sin^2 \alpha + 2t^2 - 2 cos \alpha t^2 sin^2 \alpha - 2 cos \alpha t^2 + t^2 cos^2 \alpha sin^2 \alpha + cos^2 \alpha t^2 - (t sin \alpha - t sin \alpha cos \alpha)(t sin \alpha - t sin \alpha cos \alpha) =$$
$$= 2t^2 sin^2 \alpha + 2t^2 - 2 cos \alpha t^2 sin^2 \alpha - 2 cos \alpha t^2 + t^2 cos^2 \alpha sin^2 \alpha + cos^2 \alpha t^2 - (t sin \alpha - t sin \alpha cos \alpha)^2 =$$
$$= 2t^2 sin^2 \alpha + 2t^2 - 2 cos \alpha t^2 sin^2 \alpha - 2 cos \alpha t^2 + t^2 cos^2 \alpha sin^2 \alpha + cos^2 \alpha t^2 - t^2 sin^2 \alpha + 2 t^2 sin^2 \alpha cos \alpha - t^2 sin^2 \alpha cos^2 \alpha = $$
$$= t^2 (2 sin^2 \alpha + 2 - 2 cos \alpha sin^2 \alpha - 2 cos \alpha + cos^2 \alpha sin^2 \alpha + cos^2 \alpha - sin^2 \alpha + 2 sin^2 \alpha cos \alpha - sin^2 \alpha cos^2 \alpha) = $$
$$= t^2 (3 - 2 cos \alpha)$$
Therefore, $\sqrt{Det(J^TJ)} = t \sqrt{3 - 2 cos \alpha}$
We can calculate the integral:
$$\int_M \sqrt{x + 3z}\  d \lambda_2 = \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^1 \sqrt{t cos \alpha + 3(t - tcos \alpha)} \cdot t \sqrt{3 - 2 cos \alpha} \ d t \ d \alpha = $$
$$= \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^1 (3 - 2cos \alpha) \cdot t^{\frac{3}{2}} \ d t \ d \alpha = $$
$$= \frac{2}{5} \int_0^{2 \pi} 3 - 2cos \alpha \ d \alpha =$$
$$= \frac{12 \pi}{5} $$

Start with a parametrization of the surface; for that, start with a parametrization of the ellipse. And yes, certainly with the cone point (the origin) in there, this will not be a manifold.

Ok, the cone point is not there, my mistake.  I will edit my original question. As for the parametrization of eclipse - I don't know how to do that. It makes sense if we can go to $2$ dimensions with such parametrization, but I don't see a way to unitilize those $2$ equations describing the eclipse for that.

It’s easier than you think. Start with $x$ and $y$ and then do $z$.

Ohhh, $r=1$ form the first solution and then: $x = cos \alpha$, $y = sin \alpha$, $z = 1 -cos \alpha$. Therefore we can integrate over z running from 0 to $1 -cos \alpha$ and then over $\alpha$. I'm sorry, I've been fighting with that for a long long time and was a bit frustrated with lack of progress.

How about the manifold? There is no room for any trick. It's just my lack of knowledge in this one. I have no idea of proving such thing.

Could I just take my simplified cylindrical parametrization (with $r = 1$) and show that it's invertible? But in that case, how to handle the changes on $z$ that is going from $0$ to $1-cos \alpha$?

No, you have not yet parametrized the cone.

Ok, then I got stuck on the integral and still have no idea on manifold.

You need to write down the parametrization of the cone.  Do it. Then you need to calculate the surface integral using that parametrization. Review how to do that. I suggest you use variables $\alpha,t$. Write $x,y,z$ as functions of those two parameters.

In case you haven't parameterized a surface like this before, you may find this post helpful.

@user170231 thank you, I think I get it now. I will add my solution as described in edited question.

There you go. Well done.

$x = t\cos \alpha\\
y = t\sin \alpha\\
z = t(1-\cos \alpha)$
Your issue seems to be with the calculation of the Jacobian.
We want to find
$\|dS\| = \|(\frac {\partial x}{\partial t},\frac {\partial y}{\partial t},\frac {\partial z}{\partial t})\times (\frac {\partial x}{\partial \alpha},\frac {\partial y}{\partial \alpha},\frac {\partial z}{\partial \alpha})\|$
$(\cos \alpha,\sin \alpha,1-1\cos\alpha)\times (-t\sin\alpha,t\cos\alpha,t\sin\alpha) = (t-t\cos \alpha, t\sin\alpha, t)\\
\|(t-t\cos \alpha, t\sin\alpha, 1)\| = t\sqrt {3-2\cos\alpha}$
This product of this jacobian and the integrand will be something easier to work with.

Ohh, that would change a lot! But why do you have $t - t cos \alpha$ in the first vector? I think it should be $1 - cos \alpha$ @user317176

Also, could you describe a little more how did you get that result? I thought that I need to multiply the transpose of my matrix (of partial derivatives)( with the original matrix of partial derivatives) and then calculate the square root of determinant of the matrix that I would get as a result of multiplication.

The normal vector is not quite right although the Jacbobian turned out fine

Thanks for pointing out my error with that partial derivative.  I have fixed it.

@user170231 ok, could you show me how did you calculate that $t \sqrt{3 - 2cos \alpha}$?

We take the partial derivatives with respect to the parameters.  The cross-product gives a vector that is normal to the surface.  The magnitude of this vector is equal to the area of a parallelogram in the tangent plane with edge lengths equal to $dt$ and $d\alpha$

As Ted Shifrin said in the comment, my calculation of $J^T J$ had errors in it. That was the main problem in my solution. Thank you for help! @user317176

Could you have a look at my last post? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4948174/z-xy-intersects-with-y-2x2-on-a-curve-points-on-the-curve-are-connecte

Its the last one from those exercises that I wasn't able to do myself. If you had any idea, your help would be much appreciated - you are way better in analysis than me. @user317176
