$A= \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3:x^2+2y^2+z^2 < 4z\}$ limit: $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n} \int_A \frac{y^2z}{\ln(x^2+2y^2+n) - \ln(n)} \ d\lambda_3$
$A= \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3:x^2+2y^2+z^2<4z\}$. Calculate the limit:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n} \int_A \frac{y^2z}{\ln(x^2+2y^2+n) - \ln(n)} \ d\lambda_3$$
Solution:
First, I can parametrize the set $A$ with:
$$x = r \cos \alpha$$
$$\sqrt{2} y = \ r \sin \alpha \implies y = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \ r \sin \alpha$$
The jacobian of that parametrization is equal to $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} r$
From that I get:
$$ x^2+2y^2+z^2<4z \iff r^2 \cos^2 \alpha + r^2 \sin^2 \alpha + z^2 < 4z \iff z^2 - 4z + r^2 < 0$$
So we get that: $x \in (2 - \sqrt{4 - r^2}, 2 + \sqrt{4 - r^2})$
Then:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n} \int_A \frac{y^2z}{\ln(x^2+2y^2+n) - \ln(n)} \ d\lambda_3 = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_A \ \frac{y^2z}{ \ln \left( 1+ \frac{x^2+2y^2}{n} \right)^n } \ d\lambda_3$$
Here I would like to use Dominated convergence theorem. Therefore I need...
A function that would bound the function under my limit. That can be: $f(x,y,z) = y^2 z$ since the logarithm in the denominator is smaller than 1 since it goes to $x^2 + 2y^2$ from the bottom up and on the given set $A$, the value of $x^2 + 2y^2$ will be smaller than $1$. Function $f(x,y,z)$ needs to be integrable over $A$ and I need to check that.
A second function that would be the limit of functions functions under my limit. Therefore I can take: $g(x,y,z) = \frac{y^2 z}{x^2 + 2y^2}$. Function $f(x,y,z)$ needs to be integrable over $A$ and I need to check that:
$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^{\infty} \int_{2 - \sqrt{4 - r^2}}^{2 - \sqrt{4 + r^2}} r \cos^2 \alpha \cdot z \ dz \ dr \ d \alpha$$
... and that looks like a total mess so I'm not sure if it's any good.

"on the given set $A$, the value of $x^2+2y^2$ will be smaller than $1$" - actually $x^2+2y^2 < 4$. That last integral (which should have $r \leq 2$) may not be as bad as it looks. But a transformation to $\tilde x=x, \tilde y=y\sqrt{2}, \tilde z=z-2$ then to spherical coordinates might be even nicer.

Sketch:
On $A$, $x^2+2y^2<4z-z^2$. The LHS is non-negative, so the RHS must be non-negative which gives $z \in [0,4]$. Thus,
\begin{align*}
A &\subset B := \{(x,y,z): z \in [0,4], x^2+2y^2<\max_{z \in [0,4]} 4z-z^2\}\\
 &\subset C := \{(x,y,z): z \in [0,4], x^2+y^2<4\}~.
\end{align*}
On $C$,
$$\Big|\frac{y^2z}{\ln(x^2+2y^2+n) - \ln(n)}\Big| \le \Big|\frac{4y^2}{\ln(1+\frac{x^2+2y^2}{n})}\Big| \le \Big|\frac{4y^2}{\ln(1+x^2+2y^2)}\Big| \le M$$
for some finite $M$ (I checked the last step by plotting but please verify!).
Also, the second last quantity is not continuous at $(0,0)$ but that is a set of measure $0$.
Thus,$$|I| \le \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\int_{z \in [0,4], x^2+y^2 \le 4}M \mathrm{dx}\mathrm{dy}\mathrm{dz} = 0.$$

The last inequality comes from the fact that $x^2 + 2y^2 < 4$, right? So $y<4$ and $4y^2 < 64$. The problem is, $x^2+2y^2$ under the logarithm can be arbitrary small, making whole denominator arbitrary small, and the whole expression arbitrary large.

No you can compute the limit by taking $y \to 0$ or $x \to 0$ and see that the numerator goes to zeros faster than the denominator (depends on the order of the limit and hence not continuous at $(0,0)$). I will do one direction here. First take $x \to 0$ to take that out. Then $\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{4y^2}{\ln(1+2y^2)} = \lim_{y \to 0}2 \frac{2y^2}{\ln(1+2y^2)} = 2$.

Oh, I think that actually solves the problem. So the whole limit seems to be indeed 0.

No the limit does not exist as $\lim_{x \to 0} \lim_{y \to 0} f(x,y) = 0$ and $\lim_{y \to 0} \lim_{x \to 0} f(x,y) = 2$ but the quantity is bounded nevertheless.

Right, I get it now.Thank you!

Maybe you could have a look at my other question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4947297/prove-that-line-segments-connecting-eclipse-to-0-0-0-create-a-manifold-and-cal?noredirect=1#comment10579191_4947297

I'm having trouble with this one as well @Sounak
