$A = \{ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 2x + 2y \} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$.Calculate $\int_A xyz \ d \lambda_3$. I need to verify my solution.
$A = \{ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 2x + 2y \} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$
Calculate:
$$\int_A xyz \ d \lambda_3$$

Solution:
We know that: $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 > 0$ and therefore $2x + 2y > 0 \iff x + y > 0$
We can transform the inequality in such way that it resembles sphere:
$$x^2 - 2x + y^2 - 2y + z^2 < 0 \iff (x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 + z^2 < 2$$
We have a sphere with central point at $(1,1,0)$ and radius equal to $\sqrt{2}$.
In our integral we can use spherical coordinates to get:

$x = 1 + r \ cos{\theta} \ cos{\phi}$
$y = 1 + r \ cos{\theta} \ sin{\phi}$
$z = r \ sin{\theta}$

And jacobian equal to $r^2 \ cos{\theta}$ (that is the standard jacobian for spherical parametrization).
Form that we would receive an integral:
$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} \int_0^{\sqrt{2}} (1 + r \ cos{\theta} \ cos{\phi})(1 + r \ cos{\theta} \ sin{\phi})(r \ sin{\theta}) \cdot r^2 \ cos{\theta} \ dr \ d \phi \ d \theta$$
But we don't even need to calculate that since as Andreas points in the first comment: "(the) sphere is symmetrical with respect to the $x-y$ plane, i.e., it's invariant under reversing the sign of $z$. But the integrand reverses sign also when you reverse the sign of $z$. So the integral is $0$".

Your sphere is symmetrical with respect to the $x$-$y$ plane, i.e., it's invariant under reversing the sign of $z$. But the integrand reverses sign also when you reverse the sign of $z$. So the integral is $0$.

You seem to have forgotten that your ball is centered at $(1,1,0)$, not the origin. And you did not do your completing the square correctly.

@AndreasBlass so you say that my solution is correct?

@thefool I agree with your final result, $0$, but I didn't  read the computation leading to it.

Without changing coordinates,$$\int_{\text{lower hemisphere}}^{\text{upper hemisphere}}z , dz = 0$$

Same two comments as Ted. More precision about the second one; $x^2 - 2x + y^2 - 2y + z^2 < 0$ is not equivalent to $(x-2)^2 + (y-2)^2 + z^2 < 16$ but to  $(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 + z^2 <2$.

Ok, thank you. Now I see. But what do those 2 comments mean? What changes if my ball is centered at (1,1,0) and not the origin? I don't understand what it means that "you did not do your completing the square correctly". @AnneBauval

"you did not do your completing the square correctly" means precisely the main part of my comment. $x^2-2x$ is not the "beginning of" the square of $x-2$, but of $x-1$. And since your ball is centered at $(1,1,0)$, you should write $x=\color{red}{1+}r\cos\theta\cos\phi$ and $y=\color{red}{1+}r\cos\theta\sin\phi$.

Ok, now I understand, thank you @AnneBauval. I will edit my post and try to apply that further in my solution.

Better apply Andreas' first comment.

I have lifted your original post and made a few edits to correct errors.
$$x+y > 0$$
$$x^2 - 2x + y^2 - 2y + z^2 < 0 \iff (x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 + z^2 < 2$$
We have a sphere with central point at $(1,1,0)$ and radius equal to $\sqrt {2}$.
In our integral we can use spherical coordinates to get:

$x = 1 + r \cos{\theta} \cos{\phi}$
$y = 1 + r \cos{\theta} \sin{\phi}$
$z = r \sin{\theta}$

And jacobian equal to $r^2 \cos{\theta}$
From that:
$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} \int_0^\sqrt{2} (1+r \cos{\theta} \cos{\phi})(1+r \cos{\theta} \sin{\phi})(r \sin{\theta}) \cdot r^2 \cos{\theta} \ dr \ d \phi \ d \theta = 0$$
An examination of the integrand and the symmetry of $A$ suggests from the beginning that this should integrate to $0.$  We have a hemisphere were $z > 0$ and one where $z < 0$ and these are going to cancel each other out.

Oh, I've just edited my original post in the same way. Thank you!

Could you have a look at this one? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4947297/m-is-composed-of-line-segments-connecting-ellipse-to-0-0-0-calculate-integra?noredirect=1#comment10580002_4947297 @user317176

Using suggestions in the comments I was able to make great progress in that one, but I still get an integral that i'm unable to solve.

We can formalize the idea of symmetry by using a different change of coordinates:
\begin{align}
x &= u, \\
y &= v, \\
z &= -w.
\end{align}
The Jacobian matrix of transformation $\varphi(u,v,w) = (u,v,-w)$ is diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}(1,1-1)$, so the absolute value of its determinant is $1$. Furthermore, $\varphi(A) = A$ and hence $$\int_A xyz\,dxdydz = -\int_Auvw\,dudvdw.$$
This implies that the integral is $0$.
