$z = xy$ intersects with $y = 2x^2$ on a curve. Points on curve are connected to $(0,0,0)$ by a line segment. Area of segment. Solution verification.
A surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with equation $z = xy$ intersects a surface with equation $y = 2x^2$ along some curve. Each point of the arc of this curve contained in the area $0 < z < 1$ is connected by a line segment to the point $(0,0,0)$. The sum of these segments (without ends) forms the surface of $M$. Determine that $M$ is a manifold and calculate the area of the surface of $M$.
Graph of $z = xy$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ looks like that:

Graph of $y = 2x^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ looks like that:

So we can imagine that some curve on $z = xy$ plane that is the reflection of $y = 2x^2$ curve that lays in the plane underneath. We can now imagine that we connect each point of that curve with the point (0,0,0) and need to calculate the surface of the plane that we obtain by doing so.
In the intersection we know that:

$y = 2x^2$
$z = xy \implies z = 2x^3$

We know that: $z \in (0,1) \implies x \in \left( 0,\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \right)$
I would like to integrate over $x$ and $t \in (0,1)$, where:

for $t = 0$ we would be in point $(0,0,0)$
for $t = 1$ we would be in points on curve

Therefore, we get such a parametrization:

$x \to tx$
$y \to 2tx^2$
$z \to 2tx^3$

$$\begin{pmatrix} x & t \\ 2x^2 & 4tx \\ 2x^3 & 6tx^2 \end{pmatrix}$$
From that I can calculate jacobian:
$$\begin{pmatrix} x & t \\ 2x^2 & 4tx \\ 2x^3 & 6tx^2 \end{pmatrix}^T \cdot \begin{pmatrix} x & t \\ 2x^2 & 4tx \\ 2x^3 & 6tx^2 \end{pmatrix} = $$
$$= \begin{pmatrix} x & 2x^2 & 2x^3 \\ t & 4tx & 6tx^2 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} x & t \\ 2x^2 & 4tx \\ 2x^3 & 6tx^2 \end{pmatrix} = $$
$$= \begin{pmatrix} x^2 + 4x^4 + 4x^6 & xt +8tx^3 + 12tx^5 \\ xt +8tx^3 + 12tx^5 & t^2 + 16t^2x^2 + 36t^2 x^4 \end{pmatrix}$$
From that I calculate the determinant:
$$(x^2 + 4x^4 + 4x^6)(t^2 + 16t^2x^2 + 36t^2 x^4) - (xt +8tx^3 + 12tx^5)^2 =$$
$$= (x^2 + 4x^4 + 4x^6)(t^2 + 16t^2x^2 + 36t^2 x^4) - (xt + 8tx^3 + 12tx^5)(xt + 8tx^3 + 12tx^5) =$$
$$= x^2t^2 + 16t^2x^4 + 36t^2x^6 + 4t^2x^4 + 64t^2x^6 + 144t^2 x^8 + 4t^2x^6 + 64t^2x^8 + 144t^2x^{10} - x^2t^2 - 8t^2x^4 - 12t^2x^6 - 8t^2x^4 - 64t^2x^6 - 96t^2x^8 - 12t^2x^6 - 96t^2x^8 - 144t^2x^{10} =$$
$$= 4t^2x^4 + 16t^2x^6 + 16t^2x^8 = 4t^2x^4 (1 + 4x^2 + 4x^4)$$
Then we know that square root of that is equal to $\sqrt{4t^2x^4 + 16t^2x^6 + 16t^2x^8}$
From that we calculate the integral:
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}} \sqrt{4t^2x^4 + 16t^2x^6 + 16t^2x^8} \ dx \ dt = $$
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}} \sqrt{ 4(t^2x^4 + 4t^2x^6 + 4t^2x^8)} \ dx \ dt = $$
$$= 2 \int_0^1 t \int_0^{\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}} \sqrt{x^4(1 + 4x^2 + 4x^4)} \ dx \ dt = $$
$$= 2 \int_0^1 t \int_0^{\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}} \sqrt{x^4(1 + 2x^2)^2} \ dx \ dt = $$
$$= 2 \int_0^1 t \int_0^{\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}} x^2(1 + 2x^2) \ dx \ dt = $$
$$= 2 \int_0^1 t \int_0^{\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}} x^2 + 2x^4 \ dx \ dt = $$
$$= 2 \int_0^1 t \left( \int_0^{\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}} x^2 \ dx + \int_0^{\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}} 2x^4 \ dx \right) \ dt = $$
$$= 2 \int_0^1 t \left(\frac{1}{6} + \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{\frac{5}{3}} \right) \ dt = $$
$$= 2 \left(\frac{1}{6} + \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{\frac{5}{3}} \right) \int_0^1 t \ dt = $$
$$= 2 \left(\frac{1}{6} + \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{\frac{5}{3}} \right) \frac{1}{2} = $$
$$= \left(\frac{1}{6} + \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{\frac{5}{3}} \right)$$
Does it look correct?

If you want the surface area, then the integrand is 1.  You will need the jacobian for your coordinate system.  And I would parameterize with $x$ instead of $z.$

@user317176 I think I made it. Does it look correct?

When you pull the $t^2$ out from under the radical, it becomes $t.$

Right, my bad. I've fixed that. Is it correct now? @user317176

Let's see.  When you pull out the 4, from under the radical, is there the same problem?  And, I think the limits for $x$ should be $-\sqrt[3]{\frac 12}$ to $\sqrt[3]{\frac 12}.$  Of course you could take the lower limit for $x$ as $0$ and double the integral, so these to issues cancel each other out.

You took out a factor 4 from the square root, but then wrote it as 4 instead of 2. That is why your final result is a factor 2 too large. Otherwise the calculation is fine, and the result is the same that I got (using an entirely different approach based on the inner prodfuct of two vectors).

@user317176 I don't think $x$ should move from $- \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}}$ to $\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}}$ since I take those values from $z \in (0,1)$ and therefore, values of $x$ are only positive for all values of $z$.

The easiest way to parametrize the given curve is to choose $x$ as parameter, because then we have $(x , y, z) = (x, 2x^{2}, 2x^{3})$. Other choices are possible but would only complicate matters.
We note that for positive $x$ the $z$-value is also positive, whereas a negative value for $x$ leads to a negative value for $z$. It follows that the limits of integration are $x = 0$ and $x = 2^{-1/3}$.
Points on the curve are connected by line segments to the origin, $(0,0,0)$. As a result a point $(x,y,z)$ and a nearby point $(x',y',z')$ form in combination with the origin a triangle. The surface area of such a small and narrow triangle is $\delta S = \frac {1}{2} L^2 \delta \phi$. Here $L$ is the length of the line segment.
The most difficult part of this exercise is to derive an expression for the small angle $\delta \phi$, in terms of $\delta x$. One correct way is to use the formula for the inner product of two vectors, in connection with the cosine of their angle. This computation is somewhat lengthy, but not too difficult. Once you have this expression, you can write the surface area of the manifold as an integral over the surface element $\delta S$, which becomes an integral over $\delta x$ between the integration limits as already determined.
The result I get is $S = \frac {1}{6} + \frac {1}{5} (1/2)^ {2/3}$
